# Can we automate e-charts data in angular application using protractor

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I am working on test automation using Protractor tool.
The application has one chart module, which displays liner graph data.
When we hover on the graph data tool tip is displayed with x and y axis values.

Do we have any package in protractor to validate such chart data in test automation ?

Comment: this question has been asked multiple times. look up the answer. in nutshell - yes you can, though you'll need so much time for this, that many people give up on this idea